# replacing specific parts of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
dynamic[elements][0][slider][image1]
```

Which also could be:

```
dynamic[elements][0][slider][image1]
dynamic[elements][0][abc][image1]
dynamic[elements][0][static][image1]
dynamic[elements][0][fronter][image1]
dynamic[elements][0][xyz][image1]
```

That I would like to first change "dynamic" to "main" and then slider,abc,static,fronter or xyz (or something completely different) to "value"

So the solution I am looking for should return:

```
main[elements][0][value][image1]
main[elements][0][value][image1]
main[elements][0][value][image1]
main[elements][0][value][image1]
main[elements][0][value][image1]
```

How can this be accomplished? I am thinking that a pregex that targets the third [] could be a solution, so I tried the following:

```
var line = 'dynamic[elements][0][value][image1]';
line.replace('dynamic', 'main');
line.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, 'value');
```

But I dont know how to replace the third brackets content and the above try doesn't really work.

Comment: if the third token is the only numeric index `line.replace(/\[\d+\]\[(.*?)\]/, "[value]")`

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
.replace(/^[^\][]*(\[[^\][]*]\[\d+]\[)[^\][]*(].*)/g, 'main$1value$2')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TWpu93/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^\][]*` - 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`
- `(\[[^\][]*]\[\d+]\[)`  - Group 1 matching:

  - `\[`  - a literal `[`
  - `[^\][]*` - 0 or more chars other than `[` and `]`
  - `]\[`  - a literal `][` substring
  - `\d+` -  1 or more digits
  - `]\[` - a literal `][` substring
- `[^\][]*` - 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`
- `(].*)` - Group 2 matching `]` and then any 0+ chars other than line break chars.

Note: the `]` inside a character class *must* be escaped, while when outside of the character class, it does not have to be escaped.

The `main$1value$2` is the replacement pattern inserting `main` at the start, then pasting Group 1 contents (with the `$1` backreference), then inserting `value` and then the contents of Group 2.

```js
var ss = ['dynamic[elements][0][slider][image1]', 'dynamic[elements][0][abc][image1]', 'dynamic[elements][0][static][image1]', 'dynamic[elements][0][fronter][image1]', 'dynamic[elements][0][xyz][image1]'];
var rx = /^[^\][]*(\[[^\][]*]\[\d+]\[)[^\][]*(].*)/g;
var subst = "main$1value$2";
for (var s of ss) {
 console.log(s, "=>", s.replace(rx, subst));
}
```

Comment: Best explained answer. I didn't even manage to finish my regex. Well-crafted!

Comment: Very complete. As a side note, wouldn't be simpler to first `.replace` "dynamic", as suggested by the OP? PS: congratulations for your 200k ;P

Comment: @Mistalis: Thanks. It is possible to replace in several steps, sure, it is even possible to use a callback method to count `\[.*?]` matches to replace the necessary one with the required `value`. However, it seems a single regex solution with capturing groups should suffice.